Microsoft Entity Framework - SQL query too much nested - predicados LinqKit
Numa app contruída em .NET Core 2.1 a certa altura o meu código faz um SQL query do tipo:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using LinqKit;
using Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel;

/...

            var prn = PredicateBuilder.New<ExcelMercadosModel>(false);

            foreach (var pn in Products)
                prn = prn.Or(e => e.ProductName == pn.Produto && e.Mercados == pn.Mercado);

            List<ExcelMercadosModel> mm = Mercados.Where(l => l.Month == Month)
                            .Where(prn)             // -> too nested here...
                            .ToList();
            mm = mm.Where(prm)
                            .ToList();


No entanto por haver 831 produtos, o query dá erro: "// trying to deal with: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries."
Vendo o query no output do Visual Studio, obtenho algo parecido com:
SELECT *
FROM [tDashboardExcelMercados] AS [l]
WHERE ([l].[Month] = @__Month_0) AND (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((([l].[ProductName] = ... // blabla

O predicado é construído com prn.Or(e => e.ProductName == pn.Produto && e.Mercados == pn.Mercado)`. Acontece que ao acrescentar linhas no predicado, ele envolve-o em parentisis até ao infinito.
Como é que com a mesma tecnologia do predicado posso fazer um query baseado em IN:
SELECT *
FROM [tDashboardExcelMercados] AS [l]
WHERE ([l].[Month] = @__Month_0) AND
([l].[ProductName] IN ('......) AND l.Mercado IN ('...')) -- 831 Products

Ou seja, como é que posso aplicar o IN?

Qual o porquê da má pontuação?

"por haver 831 produtos, o query dá erro..." isso é natural, cada condição vai ter um parênteses, fica muito longo e com muitos níveis, essa query pode ter problemas de performace por causa isso, mesmo usando um in. De qualquer forma, o PredicateBuilder não tem uma método In, portanto seria mais fácil usar o Linq pra filtrar

@RicardoPontual Um simples query à tabela toda deve retornar Gigabytes. Fiz um query antes do Linq.

Fiz um query intermediário, que é lançado para o SQL Server, e localmente, no programa, fiz o query todo. Assim:
List<string> ProductNames = Products.Select(l => l.Produto).ToList();

List<ExcelMercadosModel> mm = Mercados.Where(l => l.Month == Month) 
              // query rearrangement: the use of "prn" leads to SQL query too nested
                             .Where(l => ProductNames.Contains(l.ProductName))
                             .Where(prm)
                             .ToList();

mm = mm.Where(prn).ToList(); // if this Where used above => SQL query too nested


O predicado prn era o responsável pelo query SQL demasiado lento. Assim, passei parte do query para o programa, e fiz um query mais simples e mais geral que lancei para o SQL Server.
